# Replace characters in certain postion of lines with whitespace

Tags: perl, sed, awk, formatting

I need to be able to replace, character positions *58-71* with *whitespace* on every line in a file, on *Unix / Solaris*.

Extract example:

```
LOCAX0791LOCPIKAX0791LOC   AX0791LOC095200130008PIKAX079100000000000000WL1G011             000092000000000000

LOCAX0811LOCPIKAX0811LOC   AX0811LOC094700450006PIKAX0811000000000000006C1G011             000294000000000000

LOCAX0831LOCPIKAX0831LOC   AX0831LOC094000180006PIKAX083100000000000000OJ1G011             000171000000000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Perl oneliner

```
perl -pne 'substr($_, 58, 13) = (" "x13);' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: 57,14 and x14, no? And it breaks if there are empty lines.

Comment: @Scrutinizer yes, breaks, any other line format is unexpected. No, OP said positions, not char numbers. Anyway its simple to adjust.

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
sed -r  's/^(.{57})(.{14})/\1              /' bar.txt
```

With apologies for the horrible 14 space string.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {for(i=57;i<=71;i++)$i=" "}1' file
```

output for your first line:

```
LOCAX0791LOCPIKAX0791LOC   AX0791LOC095200130008PIKAX079               WL1G011
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<STDIN>) {

   my @input = split(//, $_);
   for(my $i=58; $i<71; $i++) {
      $input[$i] = " ";
   }
   $_ = join(//, @input);
   print $_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have gawk on your Solaris box, you could try:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS = "57 14 1000"} gsub(/./," ",$2)' OFS= file
```